# Using cmd.exe in Registry Key Commands

Tags: cmd, command-prompt

I'm trying to write a context menu command (RCM). The command starts a program within the current folder that has a generic name, Alias.

This is what I've got to work so far.

```
cmd /c ""%0\alias.exe""
```

I've tried other forms like

```
"%0\alias.exe"
```

but it doesn't work. I feel it should work and that there is just a minor syntax error but can't fathom it. Any ideas?

Comment: `%0` will give you the name of the batch file itself. So in this case you're trying to run `batchfilename.cmd\alias.exe`

Comment: Mofi, Thanks for that response. I should not have used 'DOS' but then I thought Windows Command Prompt would also be wrong. Perhaps It's best explained by the following RegEdit input:
    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Run Alias - Exe {sc}\Command]
    @="\"%0alias.exe\""
I'm trying to get the batch-file-like command into a registry key  that will be executed through the RCM. It will work on Folder objects. %0 should be the full path of the folder.

Comment: Gerhard, Thanks for all that information. I think my %0 is a full pathname. It is the path to the folder I am right mouse clicking on.

Comment: no, do `echo %0 & pause` and see the result.

Comment: Gerhard, Thanks. Yes, you are right, %1 is the parameter to use. (I note that %0 is giving me the same result but %1 is the correct one to use.) I also thank you for giving me a way to check values from the right click menu. I checked the %0 and %1 values with || cmd /k "echo "%0" & echo "%1" & pause & exit" ||.

Comment: So does the answer below assist in solving the issue?

Comment: Hi Gerhard, The information you have provided has been very useful to me but it has not strictly answered the question, Why does cmd /c ""%0\alias.exe"" work and "%0\alias.exe" not work? Remember, this is not in a batch file but in a registry key. I can only think the command interpreter in the registry key cannot handle an expression in the first part of the command BUT it doesn't matter as I now have a working solution. I'm very grateful for your assistance.

Comment: It works with double, double quotes because cmd.exe will consume the first set. You however never mentioned that this is in registry anywhere in the question. The question was cmdline and batch specific.

Comment: Gerhard, My apologies. I think I put it in the title but not in the question itself. This is my first question and so I'm still finding my way. Yes, cmd /c ""%0\alias.exe"" works. I'm trying to understand why "%0\alias.exe" doesn't work. Maybe it is something to do with how commands in registry keys are processed?

Comment: because you are not understanding the concept here. See the edit in the bottom of my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `%0` which is in fact the name of your batch file.

You would need to use `%~d0` (drive letter) combined with `%~p0` (path)

So use `%~dp0`

It also already expands with the trailing `\` so you can simply do:

```
"%~dp0alias"
```

For more, from `cmd.exe` help option `call /?`

```
    %~1         - expands %1 removing any surrounding quotes (")
    %~f1        - expands %1 to a fully qualified path name
    %~d1        - expands %1 to a drive letter only
    %~p1        - expands %1 to a path only
    %~n1        - expands %1 to a file name only
    %~x1        - expands %1 to a file extension only
    %~s1        - expanded path contains short names only
    %~a1        - expands %1 to file attributes
    %~t1        - expands %1 to date/time of file
    %~z1        - expands %1 to size of file
    %~$PATH:1   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
                   environment variable and expands %1 to the fully
                   qualified name of the first one found.  If the
                   environment variable name is not defined or the
                   file is not found by the search, then this
                   modifier expands to the empty string
    %~dp1       - expands %1 to a drive letter and path only
    %~nx1       - expands %1 to a file name and extension only
    %~dp$PATH:1 - searches the directories listed in the PATH
                   environment variable for %1 and expands to the
                   drive letter and path of the first one found.
    %~ftza1     - expands %1 to a DIR like output line
```

**EDIT**

As per previous believe that `%0` is the path, it is not, it displays the batchfile name. Do this in a  batch file and see the result:

```
@echo off
echo %0
echo %~0
echo %~n0
echo %dp0
echo %~dp0
pause
```

Then, why `""%~dp0\alias.exe""` works but `"%~dp0\alias.exe"` not.
`cmd.exe` consumes the first set of quotes. this is always the case.

Comment: Hi Gerhard, Thanks for this extra information. I think I've got it now. You have answered why cmd /c ""%0\alias.exe" works. Do you think I should post a new question to find out how to get "%1\alias.exe" to work when entered into a registry key, using a new, correctly worded title?